# ng-show/hide is removing everything

Tags: angularjs

I have a dynamically populated tree list that I have shown and hidden. The problem is randomly, the entire list will vanish. Even things that don't have an ng-show are gone. I have tried pretty much everything and it still has the same effect. I am completely stumped.

```
<div class="legend" ng-show="legend">
<div class="upper_legend">
    <span>Layer Legend</span>
</div>
<div class="lower_legend">
        <div style="padding-left: 8px; min-height:10px" ng-repeat="layer in index.currentLayers track by $index">
            <img src="images/down-arrow.png" style="cursor:pointer" width="10px" height="10px"
                 ng-click="index.currentLayers[$index].show= !index.currentLayers[$index].show"/><span
                    ng-click="index.currentLayers[$index].provenance =!index.currentLayers[$index].provenance;openProvenance(index.currentLayers[$index])"
                    style="cursor:pointer"> {{layer.name}}</span>

            <div class="legend_data" ng-show="index.currentLayers[$index].show">
                <span ng-repeat="color in layer.legendColors">
                    <span style="min-width:50px;height:20px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;background:{{color.color}}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>&nbsp;{{color.legend}}<br>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Does anyone have any idea why that could possible be happening? It isn't consistent either. It only happens when closing the tree and only on the first item clicked (regardless of index of the item). So, if I open and close the 3rd item, closing it will blank out the tree, but I can then open and close item 1 and it is fine every time, unless I close item 3 again. The same happens with any order.

Comment: This could really use a jsfiddle or plunkr to reproduce the issue.

Comment: you're missing `</div>` tag somewhere

Comment: That was my line of thinking with the div tag, but I triple checked and none are missing. I can try to create a jsfiddle it but its a little complicated with how dynamic the code is.

Comment: Well if it's not the missing tag, it would be hard to say without a jsfiddle to test. No console errors when the issue occurs?

Comment: No, no errors. It just vanishes.

Comment: For some stupid reason, removing the upper and lower legend divs fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing closing `</div>` tag. Did you double check this (add it to end of this code block)?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it was a bad copy and paste job on my end. The tag is in there.

Comment: @MitchellIngram, outside of that users will probably need to see your controller code - can you make a https://plnkr.co/ ?

Comment: Yeah, I will have a go at it. It is just a dynamic list that is pulled from a server so it would probably take me about as much time making a jsfiddle as solving the problem.